# What Oracle ADO.NET connector to install?

Tags: oracle, datasource, connector

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle data source and I'm looking for the simplest ADO.NET connector to use. I'm not finding a clear answer. What Oracle data source connector should I be installing?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "the simplest ADO.NET connector"? Once you are connected they are all (almost) the same.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The problem is getting connected so I want to know where I can find the connector that doesn’t require the client.

Comment: If you want to connect to Oracle without an Oracle Client then the only possibility is the **ODP.NET Managed Driver**, you can download it from here: [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to install the ODP.NET connector and connect to a publicly hosted Oracle server by installing the driver from the below link (latest version):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html

(See -  Download the ODP.NET, Managed Driver Xcopy version only)

Run the following command from command prompt as Administrator:

```
install_odpm.bat c:\oracle both true
```